# What is the collective term for policy, standard and guideline?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, collective-nouns

I know they are distinct, but if wanted to refer to them as a single entity in the distance how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with commentators that context is desirable but in some contexts you may use “rubric”, which in general refers to a set of evaluative criteria, quality definitions, and authoritative rules.